# Перемещение спрайта из одной точки в другую

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте.
Возник вопрос, пытаюсь сделать анимацию перемещения спрайта из одной точки в другую с помощью Canvas. Как бы всё вроде получилось, но картинка оставляет за собой след. Как можно от этого следа избавиться?
На одном сайте писалось, что нужно заново перерисовывать объекты в кадре, но как мне кажется, если будет большое количество спрайтов в одном кадре, то будут тормоза. Есть ли другой способ?

Answer (score 1):

1. **Перерисуйте фоном** то место, где был спрайт. Можно использовать метод `clipRect(Rect rect)`, чтобы лишнее не перерисовывать.
2. Нарисуйте спрайт в новых координатах.
3. Вызовите метод `View.invalidate( Rect r )`, указав прямоугольник, в котором был спрайт.
4. Вызовите метод `View.invalidate( Rect r )`, указав новый прямоугольник спрайта.

Метод `View.invalidate( Rect r )` заставит систему перерисовать только ту часть окна, в которой произошли изменения. `View` -  это тот компонент, в котором вы рисуете на `Canvas`.

См. также [developer.android.com/View#Drawing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#Drawing)