# Как не перерисовывать фон, а только двигающиеся по экрану объекты

Tags: java, android, разработка-игр, android-canvas

Наверняка есть способы не перерисовывать статичный монотонный фон, а только изменять положение объектов на нем. Как это осуществляется ? Я рисую на канве.

Comment: а почему вы думаете, что способ есть?

Comment: Потому, что штука эта значительно снимет нагрузку и с моими примерными представлениями о технологии, предполагаю, что подобный механизм должен быть.  И во-вторых где то мельком читал статьи, где шел разговор о слоях,  о том что можно не перерисовывать,  о неких пулах, чтобы не удалять старые объекты.  Вот мне и интересно во первых какие способы, есть на канве. Ну и что придумано в opengl

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/237805  вот например

Comment: OpenGL с канвой не имеет ничего общего. OpenGL рисует прямиком в видеопамять. Канва это абстракция, которая может быть имплементирована как угодно.

Comment: Ясно,  что это не одно и то же,  но и тот и другой рисуют,  а мне интересно как можно рисовать не отрисовывая полностью весь фон . Лучше конечно узнать как можно это сделать на канвн,  но если канва не предоставляет таких возможностей, то остается opengl . Ясное дело, все возможное в библиотеках уже реализовано,  но заглянув под капот движка не так просто понять, как он выполняет это

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если фон совсем не движется, то берете кусочек фона, восстанавливаете на месте где был спрайт, а спрайт рисуете на новом месте.

На канве много чего не придумаешь. Вот к примеру:
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F

Андроид начаная с 4.0 имеет аппратный двойной буфер, насколько я помню.

Comment: Ну да, это первое что приходит в голову.  И если подумать, то создание нижнего слоя и перерисывка на нем объектов в принципе происходит по той же схеме, на месте где был спрайт рисует снова фон. Но ведь должен быть код,который все это делает по умному, используя как можно меньше ресурсов,  не создавая каждый раз новую заплатку на фон, а брать готовое, что хранится в памяти.  На канве не прумаешь говорите,  а нам чем придумать можно? Остается только opengl ведь? И какие там возможны схемы?

Comment: Найдите любую библиотеку для 2D графики, там все это уже решено.

Comment: Знаете открыв библиотеку AndEngine не так просто понять как там решен этот вопрос,  для этого хотя бы надо знать примерно как она решается,  чтобы в нужном месте ковырять движок.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел статью про уменьшение частоты перерисовок. https://xamdev.ru/layout-performance-on-android/      И [Рисование фона игры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/456131) предложено разделить экран на яйчейки и рисовать только те что изменились.  В общем решения для частных случаев.

Comment: Появляется вопрос,  а что если самому surfaceview в xml разметке задать этот фон,  а не каждый раз самому перезаливать в методе  onDraw